# Hosting Nuget Gallery locally via localhost, cannot access its feed from Visual Studio Library Package Manager - returns 404 Not Found

Tags: localhost, nuget

I set up and installed the NuGet Gallery via:

> localhost:55880

I can manually navigate to the site:

[image]

But, when I try to add this URL as a package source in Visual Studio:

[image]

And then go to Package Manager Console, I get a 404 Not Found error:

[image]

**QUESTION**: Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feed itself is located at `http://localhost:55880/api/v2`. It should be on the page you took a screenshot of.

Comment: That did it, with the exception of I had to omit the "nuget" part of the path you describe above.  Thanks!!!  I have to remember MVC routing!